# Dynamically add 3rd party .js dependency for directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created an AngularJS module called, [ngMap](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps), and two of users asked me to load javascript `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js` dynamically whenever it is required, so that users don't have to add this .js into their head to show a map on their page when required.

The question arise is how to load this script dynamically then initialize the .js dependent directives.

Is it possible to delay loading of directives until required .js is loaded?

Comment: I tried to wrap the dependent directives with 'lazy-load' directive, but I am not sure this is good approach, http://plnkr.co/edit/9xS4Q3YGGHaLdmHUv7zs?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Since not having different answer from members, I would like to post my own solution although I am not sure this is good.

I have wrapped 3rd party .js dependent directives into a directive called `lazy-load` with the value of script source.

This directive simply delay the initialization of the script until the 3rd party .js is loaded using $timeout and $interval by removing html and adding it back.

```
app.directive('lazyLoad', function($interval, $compile, $timeout) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      (!tAttrs.lazyLoad) && console.error("requires lazy-load");
      var savedHtml = tElement.html(), src = tAttrs.lazyLoad;
      if (document.querySelector("script[src='"+src+"']")) {
        return false;
      }

      tElement.html('');  // will compile again after script is loaded
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var scriptEl = document.createElement("script");
          scriptEl.src = src;
          document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);

          var interval = $interval(function() {
            if (document.querySelector("script[src='"+src+"']")) {
              console.log('script  loaded, ' + src);
              $timeout(function() {  // give some time to execute the script
                element.html(savedHtml);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                $interval.cancel(interval);               
              }, 100);
            }
          }, 100, 10);
        }
      };
    }
  };
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

This part is html

```
<div lazy-load="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">
  <map center="Brampton" zoom="10">
    <marker position="Brampton"></marker>
  </map>
</div>
```